# Which URL made the request to my Google Apps Script?

Tags: paypal, google-apps-script

How can I determine the source URL of a GET or POST request sent to a Google Apps Script web application?

I am making a (PayPal IPN) listener script and would like to be able to distinguish weather the request came from a the test environment (sandbox) or from the live environment.

The origin of the request to the listener determines the response from the script. The listener has to send a response back to PayPal and depending on which environment the request came from, the response needs to go back either to the sandbox server or to the live server.

I am hoping to distinguish between requests from `sandbox.paypal.com` or `www.paypal.com`, in my Google Apps Script.

To work around this requirement, I have set it manually for now:

```js
  if (PPRunMode == 'test') {//in testmode send response to sandbox site  
    PPUrlBase = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
   }
  else {//url for live website
    PPUrlBase = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
   }
```

But was wondering if this can be determined automatically.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, no request-source information is provided to your Google Apps Script web application, so there is no direct way to determine where a request came from.

You do have the ability to provide parameters to your web app, though, so you could have the code in the sandboxed environment use that to indicate a test condition.

For example, this URL could be used by the sandboxed code for a GET request:

```
https://script.google.com/macros/s/---SCRIPT-ID---/exec?test=true
                                                       ^^^^^^^^^^
```

In the `doGet(e)` function, you would handle the parameter like this:

```js
function doGet(e) {
  if (e.parameter.test) { //in testmode send response to sandbox site
    PPUrlBase = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
  }
  else {//url for live website
    PPUrlBase = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
  }
  ...
}
```

For a POST request, the solution is similar. See [URL parameters](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#url_parameters) in the Web Apps and Google Sites Gadgets guide for details.

Comment: Mogsdad, thank you for the suggestion, this is an elegant solution. I implemented it, changed the test form to with "?test=true" parameter and changed the script to test for that value. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

If you publish your Google App Script you get two urls :

> https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxsCNyssA0dzMMmsNip3DW66hiJ62ks_F1yYUn0SDu073S2dOw/**exec**
>
> https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxzpvZ9e9_vzs3d6Q0ky_RHLoYDruCl-6Xm8D6YmI4/**dev**

You can notice the difference, not sure if that is what you are pointing to

Comment: I believe the question is for the sandbox / live server at the PayPal end.

Comment: may be ..even I was not sure.. Question isn't very claear